# Kivy: Why Button is losing its property in case 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

***This question seems long but isn't. Just added code and corresponding logs for viewers reference.***

I'm experimenting with Clock.schedule_interval.

**Objective**: *Upon button press, label text initially 0 will be increment 10 times.*

I have written this in 2 ways. case 1 works fine. case 2 (few edit in case 1 code) losing button on_press property.

case 1:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, _default_time as time

kv = '''
Some:
    target: target
    tick: tick
    
    id: tick
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Label:
            id: target
            text: '0'
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .5
            
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: 
                root.chik.extend(range(int(target.text)+1, int(target.text)+ 11))
                app.con.extend([root.change] * 10)
'''

class Some(Widget):
    
    target = ObjectProperty(None)
    tick = ObjectProperty(None)
    chik = ListProperty([])
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    
    def change(self):
        print(f'From widget: {self.chik} and Label text: {self.target.text}')
        if self.chik:
            self.target.text = str(self.chik.pop(0))

class TestingApp(App):
    
    con = ListProperty([])
    
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.consume, 1)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def consume(self, *args):
        print(f'from app: {self.con}')
        if self.con:
            self.con.pop(0)()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestingApp().run()
```

Log 1:

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
from app: []
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 0
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 1
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 2
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 3
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 4
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 5
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [7, 8, 9, 10] and Label text: 6
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method 
Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [8, 9, 10] and Label text: 7
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>, <bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [9, 10] and Label text: 8
from app: [<bound method Some.change of <__main__.Some object at 0x000001DFFDFA5040>>]
From widget: [10] and Label text: 9
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
from app: []
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

**Works fine and providing desired output**

case 2 with `print(self.target.text)` produce error in `def change:`

```
rom kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, _default_time as time

kv = '''
Some:
    target: target
    tick: tick
    
    id: tick
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Label:
            id: target
            text: '0'
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .5
            
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: 
                root.chik.extend(range(int(target.text)+1, int(target.text)+ 11))
                # app.con.extend([root.change]*10) removed
'''

class Some(Widget):
    
    target = ObjectProperty(None)
    tick = ObjectProperty(None)
    chik = ListProperty([])
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    
    def change(self):
        print(f'From widget: {self.chik} and Label text: {self.target.text}') # Error here
        if self.chik:
            self.target.text = str(self.chik.pop(0))

class TestingApp(App):
    
    # con = ListProperty([]) deleted
        
    def build(self):
        self.Some = Some() # Change here
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.consume, 1) 
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def consume(self, *args):
        self.get_running_app().Some.change() # Change here
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestingApp().run()
```

Log 2 with `print(self.target.text)` in `def change:`.

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "e:\Search_GUI\practice.py", line 58, in <module>
     TestingApp().run()
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 387, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 733, in tick
     self.post_idle(ts, self.idle())
   File "E:\Search_GUI\search_env\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 776, in post_idle
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 616, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 649, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 645, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "e:\Search_GUI\practice.py", line 55, in consume
     self.get_running_app().Some.change() # Change here
   File "e:\Search_GUI\practice.py", line 41, in change
     print(f'From widget: {self.chik} and Label text: {self.target.text}')
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

case 2 without `print(self.target.text)`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock, _default_time as time

kv = '''
Some:
    target: target
    tick: tick
    
    id: tick
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Label:
            id: target
            text: '0'
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .5
            
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: 
                root.chik.extend(range(int(target.text)+1, int(target.text)+ 11))
                # app.con.extend([root.change]*10) removed
'''

class Some(Widget):
    
    target = ObjectProperty(None)
    tick = ObjectProperty(None)
    chik = ListProperty([])
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    
    def change(self):
        print(f'From widget: {self.chik}')
        if self.chik:
            self.target.text = str(self.chik.pop(0))

class TestingApp(App):
    
    # con = ListProperty([]) deleted
        
    def build(self):
        self.Some = Some() # Change here
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.consume, 1) 
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def consume(self, *args):
        self.get_running_app().Some.change() # Change here
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestingApp().run()
```

log 2 without `print(self.target.text)`:

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
From widget: []
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
From widget: []
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

**For Above Case, Nothing is happening when Button was pressed**

***I want to know why behaves like that? how should get my code working for case 2 like case 1 did?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case 2, there are two instances of `Some` being created. One is built by the line:

```
return Builder.load_string(kv)
```

And that one is the root of your App display.

Another is being created by the line:

```
self.Some = Some() # Change here
```

And this second instance is not part of your App display. So when you schedule calls to `self.consume()`, The `consume()` method calls the `change()` method of the `Some` instance that is not part of the App display. Also, the second instance does not have any of the items defined in the `kv` string, because the `kv` string has a root widget definition, but not a rule for creating instances of `Some`.

---

One way to fix this, is to change the root widget definition in `kv` to a rule by changing:

```
Some:
```

to:

```
<Some>:
```

And change the `build()` method to use that definition:

```
def build(self):
    Builder.load_string(kv)
    self.Some = Some()  # create just one instance of Some
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.consume, 1)
    return self.Some  # use that one instance as the App root widget
```

Comment: is there a way to access to ids of one widget class in another widget class in `.py file`? Similarly, how can we refer widget ids in an app class in `.py file`?

Comment: Yes, but `ids` are only created by loading `kv` and they only appear in the  root widget or root rule where they are created. You need to access an instance created from a root widget or root rule, the you can access the `ids` dictionary in that instance.